# Что такое подписка msdn, и для чего она нужна?

Tags: msdn

Какие преимущества даёт *msdn*-подписка? Возможно ли пользоваться ей на машине, не имеющей подключения к интернету? И вообще - что это такое и с чем её едят?

Comment: А где вы увидели упоминание о ней? Чтобы понимать, какой у вас может быть к ней интерес.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Компания *Microsoft* предоставляет 3 вида подписок: [DreamSpark](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DreamSpark), [BizSpark](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BizSpark) и [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx):

1. *DreamSpark* - это программа, предоставляющая студентам и аспирантам
   бесплатный доступ к инструментам проектирования и разработки
   программного обеспечения.
   Стоит заметить, что существует [несколько видов подписок DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/): для студентов и аспирантов, преподавателей и учебных заведений ([DreamSpark Premium](http://www.dreamspark.ru/support)).
2. *BizSpark* - это программа, предназначенная для [стартапов](https://special.habrahabr.ru/hello_startup/bizspark/), которая в
   своих рамках предоставляет начинающим предпринимателям возможность
   получить комплект инструментов разработки, а также лицензионного
   программного обеспечения *Microsoft*.
3. *MSDN* (также называется [подпиской Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/subscriber-benefits-vs)) - это программа, позволяющая получить весь набор инструментов разработчика *Microsoft*, включая последнюю среду разработки *Visual Studio*, с годовой подпиской *Visual Studio* или *Visual Studio с MSDN*.

При приобретении/получении любой из этих подписок вам будет выдан идентификатор *"Subscriber ID"*, который будет привязан к вашему *Microsoft Account*'у (но для этого вам придется его [активировать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/add/default.aspx)), и посредством которого вы сумеете получить доступ к продуктам от *Microsoft*, часть которых можно будет посмотреть (а также получить ключ и скачать) [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/subscriptions/downloads/) (причем продукты имеют несколько [типов ключей](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/subscriptions/cc137104.aspx)), а также появится доступ к облачным решениям ([Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/services/cloud-services/?WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=SEM_MyPI8HXg)), на которые ежемесячно будет выделяться некоторый лимит денег, который вы сможете потратить для подключения/продления необходимых вам сервисов и услуг.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение стоит отметить, что продукты, которые входят в подписку MSDN Вы можете использовать только для разработки, тестирования и демонстрации ПО. Использование продуктов в коммерческих (производственных) целях запрещено.

Comment: зависит от подписки же

Comment: Везде находится именно этот текст - "только для разработки, тестирования и демонстрации ПО. Использование продуктов в коммерческих (производственных) целях запрещено." Но он не отвечает на один важный вопрос - а можно ли использовать продукты дома в некоммерческих целях?